# Problems with jQuery slideToggle Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

Please help me find the problem with this code. I am trying to create a simple slideToggle element! I tried this first:

```
$("..").slideToggle(..,..,..)
```

My current code looks like this:

## My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Layer13copy2").click(function () {
    $("#toggle").animate({ height: 'toggle' });
  });
});
```

```css
#Layer13copy2 { 
  left: 13.85%; 
  top: 398px; 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 892px;
  height: 37px;
  z-index:5;
  background:url('../images/slidet.png') 45%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:101.4% 101%;
}

#toggle {
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: #3a97b1;
  display: block;
  left: 13.85%;
  top: 39.37%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 71.95%;
  height: 17%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Layer13copy2"></div>
<div id="toggle"></div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? The `animate` function works correctly. Are you trying to achieve this effect with `slideToggle`?

Comment: 'slideToggle' does't work with 'position:absolute;' soo am trying to replace it with that  `<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#toggle').animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        });
    $("#Layer13copy2").click(function(){
        $("#toggle").animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        });
    });
});
</script> ` but it does't work again !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#toggle').animate({ height : 'toggle' });
         $("#Layer13copy2").click(
      function(){$('#toggle').animate({ height : 'toggle' });
    });});
```

```css
     #Layer13copy2 
    { 
      position: absolute; 
      width: 292px;
      height: 37px;
      background-color:blue;
      } 
    #toggle{
        background-color: #3a97b1;
        top: 35px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Layer13copy2" >
       <div id="toggle" marginwidth="0"></div>
       </div>
```